# How to make a responsive grid with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make a grid for a non-profit organization like this - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWEBH.jpg). Here is my pure - [HTML & CSS](https://pastebin.com/04EEv8CU). But margin padding isn't the same, and responsive mode isn't okay. Also, I think my code isn't right. I've spent already 2 days making a perfect grid like that [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWEBH.jpg).

How I can fix **layout, margin padding, responsiveness**, etc?
What is the **right CSS** for this grid?

Thanks.

```css
body {
                color: #000;
                font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            }

            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
                font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            }

            .focus_area {
                width: 100%;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .focus {
                width: 33.33%;
                float: left;
                position: relative;
                padding: 2px;
            }

            .focus:last-child {
                margin-top: -118px;
            }

            .focus_text {
                width: 66.66%;
                margin-top: 248px;
                height: 248px;
                padding: 36px;
                background: rgb(156, 166, 104);
                color: #fff;
            }

            .focus_text h2 {
                text-align: center;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .focus img {            }

            .focus p {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 20px;
                color: #fff;
                text-shadow: 0 0 black;
                font-size: 22px;
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <div class="container py-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2 class="text-center">Some Title</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="container">
                <div class="focus_area">
                    <div class="focus">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/wdRy4Wv/cities-and-shelter.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                        <p>Cities & Shelters</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="focus">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VCbRdbx/education-and-training.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                        <p>Education & Training</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="focus">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/3NSF6hj/food-and-water.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                        <p>Food & Water</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="focus_text">
                        <h2>Delivering Humanitarian Relief Throughout The World</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="focus">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0BT5vp5/energy-and-environment.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                        <p>Energy & Environment</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="focus">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/bWpystL/jobs-and-business.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                        <p>Jobs & Business</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="focus">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XX9Y7yH/health-and-fitness.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                        <p>Health & Fitness</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <div class="container py-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2 class="text-center">Some Title</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Would it be okay if the solution involves flexbox or grid property? I will try to come up with it if it is okay so.

Comment: Sure. I just need to make the grid looks good with margin-padding & responsiveness.

Comment: If you need a grid, then use `display: grid` Only use `float: left` if you are stuck in the year 2009.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start, you would have to add data and images yourself, but it can be easily changed to fit your exact needs.

```css
/* These are just to make the demo look nice */
body {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  place-items: center;
}
main {
  height: 80vmin;
  width: 80vmin;
}

/* Actual code here */
main {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

div {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}


/* top right */

div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #f77;
  grid-row: span 2;
}


/* middle */

div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #7e7;
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}


/* bottom right */

div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #f77;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
  }
  div:nth-child(3),
  div:nth-child(5) {
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your code output isn't like my grid at all- https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWEBH.jpg

First, 2 images then one vertical image.
Second, a text block with green background.
Third, 2 images then one vertical image.

Comment: it has the same layout (open the snippet in full screen) with responsiveness built in (smaller screens is a two column grid instead).  You would have to add the images to their responding divs.

Comment: You'll probably want to adjust the exact sizes, paddings (gap property) and maybe the point at where it goes to two column to fit your **exact situation**.  (if you don't need two column, just remove the media query).

Comment: But I face another problem. On the `<body>` tag you've used some CSS. But I want to change the `body`  into a `<div class="focus">` and then the layout has broken. That means, I don't want to use `body {display: grid; height: 100vh; margin: 0; place-items: center;}`, instead of `body` I want to use a class like `.focus { display: grid; height: 100vh; margin: 0; place-items: center; }` and then the layout has broken.

Comment: The style in the body part is not that important, it just makes the demo look nicer because all the content is empty.  I have amended the css to mark which parts are just for show and which are important.

Answer (score 0):

I made a solution using `grid` and `flex` css properties; that way I managed to realize the layout you wanted to create.

[Edited: I didn't know posting links don't fit the guidelines, sorry :(]

Anyway, I post here a snippet code on how I managed to create the layout:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300;400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <style>
      body {
        color: #000;
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
      }

      h1,
      h2,
      h3,
      h4,
      h5,
      h6,
      p {
        font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
      }

      .focus_area {
        width: 100%;
        /* display: inline-block; */
      }

      .focus {
        /* width: 33.33%; */
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        padding: 2px;
      }

      .focus:last-child {
        /* margin-top: -118px; */
      }

      .focus_text {
        width: 100%;
        /* margin-top: 248px; */
        /* height: 248px; */
        padding: 30px;
        background: rgb(156, 166, 104);
        color: #fff;
      }

      .focus_text h2 {
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }

      .focus img {
      }

      .focus p {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 65px;
        left: 10px;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 0 0 black;
        font-size: 22px;
      }

      .grid {
        display: grid;
        flex: 0 1 65%;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, minmax(33.3%, 33.3%));
      }

      /* Grid block that goes from column 1 to column 3
         and from row 2 to row 3 */
      .grid-block-1-3 {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 3;
        grid-row-start: 2;
        grid-row-end: 3;
      }

      .grid-block-1-2 {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 2;
        grid-row-start: 3;
        grid-row-end: 4;
      }

      .grid-block-2-3 {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: 3;
        grid-row-start: 3;
        grid-row-end: 4;
      }

      .grid-block-3-4 {
        grid-column-start: 3;
        grid-column-end: 4;
        grid-row-start: 3;
        grid-row-end: 4;
      }

      .grid-block-1-3-row {
        grid-column-start: 3;
        grid-column-end: 4;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 3;
      }

      .img-height {
        height: 100%;
        background-size: contain;
      }

      .flex-layout {
        display: flex;
      }

      .second-grid {
        display: grid;
        flex: 0 1 35%;
      }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .grid {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
    
      }

      .flex-layout {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
      }

      .focus {
        flex: 0 1 215px;
      }
    }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container py-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2 class="text-center">Some Title</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container flex-layout">
      <div class="focus_area grid">
        <div class="focus">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/wdRy4Wv/cities-and-shelter.png"
            alt=""
            class="img-fluid img-height"
          />
          <p>Cities & Shelters</p>
        </div>
        <div class="focus">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/VCbRdbx/education-and-training.png"
            alt=""
            class="img-fluid img-height"
          />
          <p>Education & Training</p>
        </div>

        <div class="focus_text grid-block-1-3">
          <h2>Delivering Humanitarian Relief Throughout The World</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="focus grid-block-1-2">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/0BT5vp5/energy-and-environment.png"
            alt=""
            class="img-fluid img-height"
          />
          <p>Energy & Environment</p>
        </div>
        <div class="focus grid-block-2-3">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/bWpystL/jobs-and-business.png"
            alt=""
            class="img-fluid img-height"
          />
          <p>Jobs & Business</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="second-grid">
        <div class="focus grid-block-1-3-row">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/3NSF6hj/food-and-water.png"
            alt=""
            class="img-fluid img-height"
          />
          <p>Food & Water</p>
        </div>
        <div class="focus grid-block-3-4">
          <img
            src="https://i.ibb.co/XX9Y7yH/health-and-fitness.png"
            alt=""
            class="img-fluid img-height"
          />
          <p>Health & Fitness</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container py-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2 class="text-center">Some Title</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read [answer]. Your answer effectively is 
a [link only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) and as such does not fit the guidelines 
as an answer. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) which also applies to any other external resources such as codepen, fiddle, sandbox... Include code directly into the answer by using the Stacksnippet. If your link changes, is removed or the content of your link, the whole answer would be worthless.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about links specifically, I just edited my answer posting a snippet instead of a link. Thanks for reminding me about guidelines

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ruber. On the mobile screen images/blocks should show one by one and full-width. How I can do it?

Comment: You could use @media queries css property. I edited the snippet including media queries (I assumed 480px as max mobile size but you can modify as you like with the proper screen dimension)

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.1;
}

.card_text {
  height: 270px;
  background: rgb(156, 166, 104);
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 100px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.bolBlock p {
  left: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 black;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  --bs-gutter-x: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.bolBlock {
  padding: 1px !important;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h2 class="text-center">Some Title</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-8">
    <div class="bolBlock col-6">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/wdRy4Wv/cities-and-shelter.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
      <p>Cities & Shelters</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bolBlock col-6">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VCbRdbx/education-and-training.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
      <p>Education & Training</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card_text col-12">
      <h2>Delivering Humanitarian Relief Throughout The World</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="bolBlock col-6">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0BT5vp5/energy-and-environment.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
      <p>Energy & Environment</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bolBlock col-6">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/bWpystL/jobs-and-business.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
      <p>Jobs & Business</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="bolBlock">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/3NSF6hj/food-and-water.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
      <p>Food & Water</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bolBlock">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XX9Y7yH/health-and-fitness.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
      <p>Health & Fitness</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Velimi. Can you write some CSS for the responsive view? On the mobile screen images/blocks should show one by one and full-width.

Comment: no CSS is required just use col-xs-12, col-sm-, col-md-, col-lg-, based on your requirement
please go with this document: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/
if you are not able to get understand clearly then let me know I will update the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the solution. Used flexbox and as for the responsiveness, only the text size will affect, so adjust the text size accordingly. Also to note that I added some changes in the markup for the style purposes. Let me know if it answered your question.

```css
/* style.css */
body {
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}

.focus_area {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.focus_area .left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 66.66666%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.focus_area .right {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-width: 33.33333%;
}

.left-top, .left-bottom {
    display: flex;
}

.left .focus {
    flex: 50%;
}

.focus_text {
    background: rgb(156, 166, 104);
    color: #fff;
    flex: 2;
    display: flex;
    margin: 2px;
}

.focus_text h2 {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.focus {
    position: relative;
    padding: 2px;
}

.right .focus img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.left .focus img {  
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.focus p {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 black;
    font-size: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

/* tablet styles */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 481px) {
    .focus_area {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .focus_area .left, .focus_area .right {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .focus_text {
        padding: 50px 0px;
    }

    .focus_area .right {
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
} /* end of tablet styles */

/* styles for mobile devices */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .focus_area {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .focus_area .left, .focus_area .right {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .left-top, .left-bottom {
        display: block;
    }

    .focus_text {
        padding: 50px 0px;
    }
} /* end of mobile styles */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="text-center">Some Title</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="focus_area">
            <div class="left">
                <div class="left-top">
                    <div class="focus">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/wdRy4Wv/cities-and-shelter.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                        <p>Cities & Shelters</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="focus">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/VCbRdbx/education-and-training.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                        <p>Education & Training</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="focus_text">
                    <h2>Delivering Humanitarian Relief Throughout The World</h2>
                </div>

                <div class="left-bottom">
                    <div class="focus">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0BT5vp5/energy-and-environment.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                        <p>Energy & Environment</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="focus">
                        <img src="https://i.ibb.co/bWpystL/jobs-and-business.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                        <p>Jobs & Business</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right">
                <div class="focus">
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/XX9Y7yH/health-and-fitness.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                    <p>Health & Fitness</p>
                </div>
                <div class="focus">
                    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/3NSF6hj/food-and-water.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
                    <p>Food & Water</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container py-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="text-center">Some Title</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see you've changed the makeup. One mobile block will display one by one. How I can do it?

Comment: Do you mean in mobile, you want each image to take the full width? You can use the class names of the elements in the markup to let me know how you want in the mobile version to make things clear.

Comment: Yes, responsive means mobile version. Every image/block will display **full width** on the mobile screen.

Comment: Okay I have added the styles for mobile devices. You can change the `max-width` for the media query to match the mobile devices to your choice.

Comment: I have also added styles for tablet devices. You can simply comment it out if you don't want it so to your choice.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily get what you want by using CSS Grid :

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="c1">1</div>
            <div class="c2">2</div>
            <div class="c3">3</div>
            <div class="c4">4</div>
            <div class="c5">5</div>
            <div class="c6">6</div>
            <div class="c7">7</div>
        </div>
```

```
.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    gap: 2px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.c1, .c2,.c6,.c7 {
    grid-row: span 2;
}

.c3,.c5 {
     grid-row: span 3;
}

.c4 {
     grid-row: span 2;
     grid-column: span 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Omid, for your answer. But your code output isn't like the desired grid at all.

Comment: it was just an idea check out the link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-panini-crtuzg